# Почему не работает tablesorting?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Есть у меня задача, нужно сделать возможность сортировки таблицы по фамилии или имени.
Установил плагин от сюда http://tablesorter.com/docs/
Подключил как указано в документации.
Но не работает. Таблица у меня генерируется автоматически. В чем может быть проблема? Куда смотреть?

```
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter" align="center" border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <td>Фамилия</td>
    <th>Имя</th>
    <th>Возраст</th>
    <th>Телефон</th>
    <th>Умеет водить</th>
    <th>Статус</th>
    <th>Редактировать</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
```

Дальше идет кусок кода для пагинации, а затем вывод таблицы

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)):?>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td> <?echo $row['sname'];?> </td>
<td> <?echo $row['name'];?> </td>
<td> <?echo calculate_age($row['dateb']);;?> </td>
<td> <?echo $row['mob'];?> </td>
<td> <?echo $row['buses'];?> </td>
<td> 
<input id='input<?=$row['id']?>' name='active' type='checkbox' value ='<?=$row["active"]?>' onchange="on_change(<?=$row['id']?>)" <?php if($row['active'] == '1') {echo 'checked="checked"';} else { echo "";} ?> />
</td> 
<td> <a href = "index.php"> Изменить </a> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<? endwhile;?>
</table>
```

Comment: Без кода мы вам помочь не можем. Поделитесь кодом

Comment: Даже не знаю какой кусок выложить. @UrmuzTagizade вот вложил код в вопрос

Comment: скрипты правильно подключили?

Comment: @UrmuzTagizade как указано в документации <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> пути естественно свои

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался сам. Дело в том, что тег tbody попал в цикл. Если поставить его перед циклом, то все как надо